# error with link preview script

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, hyperlink

i have the below code of a link preview script that works like facebook  but the problem is that when i input the url `https://www.facebook.com` instead of showing me the fb logo it shows me the google chrome logo and it shows update your browser

the code

```
    <?php
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $url = url_clean($url);

    //clean url
    function url_clean($ini_url)
    {
        $uri = trim($ini_url);
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
        {
            $uri = stripslashes($uri);
        }
        $uri = strtr($uri, array_flip(get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES)));
        $uri = strip_tags($uri);
        $uri = htmlspecialchars($uri);
        return $uri;
    }
    //strip the url
    function domain_strip($url)
    {
        if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED) === FALSE)
        {
            return false;
        }
        /*** get the url parts ***/
        $parts = parse_url($url);
        /*** return the host domain ***/
        return $parts['host'];
    }   
    //get the information
    function get_dat($clean_url)
    {
        $web_site = fopen($clean_url, "r"); 
        if (!$web_site)
        {
            exit("Error");
        } 
        $info = '';
        while (!feof($web_site))
        {
            $info .= fgets($web_site, 1024);
        }
        return $info;
    }

    $string = get_dat($url);


    /// get title
    $title_regex = "/<title>(.+)<\/title>/i";
    preg_match_all($title_regex, $string, $title, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    $url_title = $title[1];

    /// get decription
    $tags = get_meta_tags($url);

    // fetch images
    $image_regex = '/<img[^>]*'.'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';
    preg_match_all($image_regex, $string, $img, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    $images_array = $img[1];
    ?>
    <div class="link_prev_container">
    <!----image_cont----->
    <?php
    if(!$images_array)
    {
        echo '';
    }
    else
    {
      echo '<div class="image_holder">';
      $k=1;
      for ($i=0;$i<=sizeof($images_array);$i++)
      {
          if(@$images_array[$i])
          {
              if(@getimagesize(@$images_array[$i]))
              {
                  list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize(@$images_array[$i]);
                  if($width >= 50 && $height >= 50 ){

                  echo "<img src='".@$images_array[$i]."' width='100' id='".$k."' >";

                  $k++;

                  }
              }
          }
      }
      echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
    <!----text inf----->
    <div class="text_inf_holder">
      <div class="title_container"><?php  echo substr(@$url_title[0],0,40) ?></div>
      <div class="brief_container"><?php  echo @$tags['description']; ?></div>
      <div class="link_container"><a class="link" href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo domain_strip($url) ?></a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

my question: what is facebook's linkpreview script searching for that the above script is not?

Comment: Is it possible that because you're not specifying a User Agent during the scraping, facebook redirects you to google chrome website?

Comment: Facebook is probably looking at your user-agent string and determine that your "browser" is too old

Comment: @Ignas im new to this so please elaborate

Comment: @Mr.coder: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

Comment: @WizKid this is all to advanced could you tell me thinking that im a noob to all this????

Comment: Facebook basically doesn't know what browser you are using when you request the page using PHP, thus thinks your browser is outdated and shows you a bunch of alternative browsers. You can easily test it by making a new script and just adding `<?php echo file_get_contents('https://www.facebook.com/'); ?>` You'd see the page that facebook would show your PHP script.

Comment: @Mr.coder: That is why I linked to Wikipedia so you could read about user-agent

Comment: ok @KevinVandenborne so how do i solve this problem????

Comment: Replacing `$web_site = fopen($clean_url, 'r');` with `$opts = array (
    'http' => array (
        'method' => "GET",
        'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.17 Safari/537.36',
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$web_site = fopen($clean_url, 'r', false, $context);` might do the trick.

Comment: @kevin yould you mind putting it in the form of an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `$web_site = fopen($clean_url, 'r');` with the following:

```
$opts = array (
    'http' => array (
        'method' => "GET",
        'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.17 Safari/537.36',
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$web_site = fopen($clean_url, 'r', false, $context);
```

If should send the user agent headers along and make Facebook think you're using chrome and hopefully bypass the browser check.

Comment: thnx man it worked but the `$tags = get_meta_tags($url);` is not getting anything why is that ?

Comment: It's likely the same issue, refer to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-set-default.php for an example and user the $opts i posted above.